# "No Bluetooth adapters found"

Tags: bluetooth

I'm using an HP 250 G3 notebook with Ubuntu 15.04 32-bit. But I can't use the bluetooth service. It says "No Bluetooth adapters found". My bluetooth status shows:

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2015-08-17 21:27:33 IST; 2min 2s ago
 Main PID: 5952 (bluetoothd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─5952 /usr/sbin/bluetoothd -n

Aug 17 21:27:33 arkya-HP-250-G3-Notebook-PC bluetoothd[5952]: bluetoothd[5952...
Aug 17 21:27:33 arkya-HP-250-G3-Notebook-PC bluetoothd[5952]: bluetoothd[5952...
Aug 17 21:27:33 arkya-HP-250-G3-Notebook-PC bluetoothd[5952]: bluetoothd[5952...
Aug 17 21:27:33 arkya-HP-250-G3-Notebook-PC bluetoothd[5952]: bluetoothd[5952...
Aug 17 21:27:33 arkya-HP-250-G3-Notebook-PC bluetoothd[5952]: bluetoothd[5952...
Aug 17 21:27:33 arkya-HP-250-G3-Notebook-PC bluetoothd[5952]: bluetoothd[5952...
Aug 17 21:27:33 arkya-HP-250-G3-Notebook-PC bluetoothd[5952]: Failed to init ...
Aug 17 21:27:33 arkya-HP-250-G3-Notebook-PC bluetoothd[5952]: Bluetooth Manag...
Aug 17 21:27:33 arkya-HP-250-G3-Notebook-PC bluetoothd[5952]: bluetoothd[5952...
Aug 17 21:27:33 arkya-HP-250-G3-Notebook-PC bluetoothd[5952]: bluetoothd[5952...
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Please help.

P.S.: Following is the output given by the command "lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb" :

```
09:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter [103c:18ec]
    Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:5776 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: OP switched to a different laptop model according to a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also a HP 250 G3 user. Bluetooth driver present is Ralink rt3290. I successfully got my Bluetooth working using the module in the link below.

https://www.github.com/dineshraj01/rtbth-dkms

you need to compile it and install it using commands given below

```
make
sudo make install
```

Works like a charm for me.
Sometimes on restart bluetooth doesn't work.
you can simply remove and add the module again using the commands below and it will work.

```
sudo rmmod rtbth
sudo modprobe rtbth
```

You can also read the instructions on the github repo given :)

Comment: Thanks.
 I've changed my laptop though :P